# Querying a database with any subset of a list of conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL database with a number of columns (say column0 .. column19).

I want to select all rows of the database which satisfy a condition of the form:

```
column0 < value0 AND column1 < value1 AND ... AND column19 < value19.
```

The catch is that I want to select rows which satisfy ANY 15 conditions out of the above.

I know I can do multiple queries will all possible combinations of 15 conditions, but I'm looking for a solution with only 1 query.

Is it possible with MySQL? Is there another database architecture which allows such queries?

Thanks

Comment: @AmirW: Are you saying you want to select a row if AT LEAST 15 of the conditions are met?

Comment: can you do or's in the statement and filter out the ones that don't have a least 15 after?

Comment: @Tbone, ORs in my case will likely give the whole database. I can use something like condition0 OR condition1 OR condition2 e.g.. where condition0 is somthing like column0 < value0 AND column1 < value1 AND ... column14 < value14, etc..  This will give what I want but I'm looking for a more elegant solution

Comment: sorry I was writing a question and accidentally hit add comment, but it looks like you got your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the below, but don't expect it'll perform particularly well!

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN column0 < value0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
      CASE WHEN column1 < value1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
      ... + 
      CASE WHEN column19 < value19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 15
```

Comment: My pleasure - just bear in mind that this isn't a particularly nice query.  That said, am not sure there's a nice way to do this - perhaps this is even optimal...  :)

Answer (score 1):

Will's answer can also be written as:

```
WHERE (  SUM( column0 < value0 ) 
       + SUM( column1 < value1 ) 
       ... + 
       + SUM( column19 < value19 ) 
      ) >= 15
```

The above will work **only in MYSQL**, not other databases. So, I suppose it's better to use the standard `CASE WHEN` than this.

---

Another way to handle such a query would be like this (`id` is the primary key of the table):

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable
    JOIN
      ( SELECT id
        FROM yourTable
        WHERE column0 < value0
      UNION ALL
        SELECT id
        FROM yourTable
        WHERE column1 < value1
      UNION ALL
        ...
      UNION ALL
        SELECT id
        FROM yourTable
        WHERE column19 < value19

      GROUP BY id
      HAVING COUNT(*) >=15
      ) AS chk  
    ON chk.id = yourTable.id
```

If there are 20 indexes (one on every `column0`, `column1`, ..., `column19`), it might, might be quicker.